# ConstraintLayout in NavigationView header doesn't take full width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-navigationview

#### Here is my `NavigationView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_test"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyleLand"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/mainGray"
    app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu">
```

#### Here is my `HeaderLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`android:layout_width="match_parent"` for `ConstraintLayout` not working. Header width is less then `NavigationView`.

When I'm trying to replace `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout`, `width` is correct.

Can somebody help me understand why does `ConstraintLayout` not fit correctly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Well I exactly don't know but you can give it a try by changing the width to 0dp and add this line in your xml and try

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
```